# Sitecore How to save items in different languages when saved via pipeline

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

Using the Sitecore `item:saved` event handler, I am trying to add items in other languages. So if you say, add a item in one language, it should automatically add the item in the other given languages when saved.

Right now, I can get all the languages from the master database. The problem is when adding a new version of the new language, it triggers itself and therefore recursive adds "infinite" new elements until it crashes. How is it possible to bypass this?

```cs
public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Item savedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

    if (savedItem.Versions.Count == 1)
    {
        // Allow only non null items and allow only items from the master database | 
        if (savedItem != null && savedItem.Database.Name.ToLower() == "master")
        {
            // Do some kind of template validation to limit only the items 
            if (savedItem.TemplateID == ID.Parse("{template id}"))
            {
                // Get all the installed languages from the master database
                var installedLanguages = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Database.GetDatabase("master"));

                // Go through every language in the list
                foreach (var language in installedLanguages)
                {

                    // Copy item to the new language
                    if (savedItem.Language.Name != language.Name)
                    {
                        using (new LanguageSwitcher(language.Name))
                        {
                            // Save the new item, but it fails since it triggers itself (the event)
                            savedItem.Versions.AddVersion();

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```cs
foreach (var language in installedLanguages)
{
    if (savedItem.Language.Name != language.Name)
    {
        var otherLanguageItem = savedItem.Database.GetItem(savedItem.ID, language);
        if (otherLanguageItem.Versions.Count == 0)
        {
            otherLanguageItem.Versions.AddVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite a while since I have done any Sitecore work and I don't currently have access to a Sitecore instance for testing out a code sample, but one way to approach this would be to put a collection of updated item ids on the context.  The approach (in pseudo code) could be inserted immediately after your template check (to keep less expensive checks earlier than more expensive ones) and would go something like:

`- retrieve collection of updated items from context or create
- if collection contains current item id, return immediately
- add current item id to collection`

I'd be happy to provide more clarity on how this would look syntactically if needed, but honestly if I write something in C# I prefer to be able to actually see it work